# How to add two Posts in a static wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, static, static-pages

All I am trying to do is to add two Posts in a wordpress Static home page. 
Such as the one in the following picture. 
I can't seem to find any option in the admin part of wordpress, and there is only one content box to post things. How do I get two or more? Thank You.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bandapt.com](http://bandapt.com/test.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit your template files if your theme doesn't have such a custom option. I suggest you to check this links:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Retrieve_a_Particular_Post

Comment: My template does support the multiple "boxes"/"posts" on the Blog page. However, what I am trying to do is have the "box" displayed twice on a static page. I don't care about (calendar/author/title) I just want the multiple boxes. Is there a pluging so I can use multiple posts in the \wp-admin site.